# Memory usage growing seems to be linked to Metal objects

Tags: swift, metal

I am currently building an app that uses Metal to efficiently render triangles and evaluate a fitness function on textures, I noticed that the **memory usage of my Metal app is growing and I can't really understand why**.

First of all I am surprised to see that **in debug mode**, according to Xcode debug panel, **memory usage grows really slowly** (about 20 MB after  200 generated images), whereas **it grows way faster in release** (about 100 MB after 200 generated images).
I don't store the generated images (at least not intentionally... but maybe there is some leak I am unaware of).

I am trying to understand where the leak (if it one) comes from but I don't really know where to start, I took a a GPU Frame capture to see the objects used by Metal and it seems suspicious to me:
[image]

Looks like there are thousands of objects (the list is way longer than what you can see on the left panel).

Each time I draw an image, there is a moment when I call this code:

```
trianglesVerticesCoordiantes = device.makeBuffer(bytes: &positions, length:  bufferSize , options: MTLResourceOptions.storageModeManaged)
triangleVerticiesColors = device.makeBuffer(bytes: &colors, length: bufferSize, options: MTLResourceOptions.storageModeManaged)
```

I will definitely make it a one time allocation and then simply copy data into this buffer when needed, but could it cause the memory leak or not at all ?

EDIT with screenshot of instruments :
[image]

**EDIT #2 : Tons of command encoder objects present when using Inspector:**
[image]

**EDIT #3 : Here is what seems to be the most suspect memory graph when analysed which Xcode visual debugger:**
[image]

And some detail :
[image]

I don't really know how to interpret this...

Thank you.

Comment: Likely not. Have you used the Leaks instrument in Instruments and the static analyzer in Xcode to attempt to narrow down the source of the leaks?

Comment: @warrenm No leak is detected but I just noticed that some float4 array has 9.61 GB "Total Bytes" (updated my answer with screenshot)

Comment: If I am looking at the right array in my code, I don't see its size increase though...

Comment: @warrenm I updated again my question this time with a view of the "All heap & anonymous VM" part, there are many Metal objects there (they fill about 95% of the list). Looks like they are command encoders but I don't understand at all why they aren't being dealocated.

Comment: I'm actually concerned by the two lines below the two highlighted lines in the first screenshot. Are you calling `malloc` or a related function without a corresponding call to `free`?

Comment: @warrenm I don't ever call malloc, I just call `withUnsafeMutableBytes` on a Swift array to read a texture I rendered with Metal, but I think Swift takes care of allocation and dealocation in this case ?

Comment: @warrenm I also updated my question with a new screenshot of the details of malloc.

Comment: The fact that no leaks are detected seems to imply a retain cycle, but I'm not sure why that would be happening, nor why running a release build would exacerbate the problem. Are you doing anything unusual with completed handlers on your command buffers that would cause them to live longer than necessary? Also, have you tried using the [Debug Memory Graph](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-visual-memory-debugger/) in Xcode?

Comment: @warrenm I don't see anything that would look like a "cycle" but I see objects owned by closures that are themselves owned by closures etc... will post a screenshot soon.

Comment: @warrenm I added a new screenshot with the Xcode visual debugger, looks like there is something with closures but I don't really know what to do, especially since even adding [weak self] to my closure body doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: It's conceivable that this is a framework bug. Have you considered filing a Radar including a copy of your project that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Did you ever determine the cause of this issue? I’m seeing a similar issue with my encoders leaking.

Comment: @grovesNL No I never did, this was just a test project so I moved to something else. Honestly that was really surprising, are you using Swift ? I remember that I had heavily used protocols which made me wonder if there wouldn't be some rare bug that could be coming from Swift, but that's really just a supposition.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Thanks for the response! My issue was apparently just a bad retain/release caused by a temporary autorelease pool (in Objective-C).